# Keras - The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, word2vec, keras-layer

I'm trying to implement skip-gram using keras. Getting error while adding the Dot() layer. The below implementation is inspired by [Dipanjan](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-feature-engineering-part-4-deep-learning-methods-for-text-data-96c44370bbfa) code. I have done some modification related to different versions of keras.

Here's what I have implemented till now :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 200
%matplotlib inline
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from string import punctuation

wpt = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

def normalize_document(doc):
    # lower case and remove special characters\whitespaces
    doc = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', doc, re.I|re.A)
    doc = doc.lower()
    doc = doc.strip()
    # tokenize document
    tokens = wpt.tokenize(doc)
    # filter stopwords out of document
    filtered_tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stop_words]
    # re-create document from filtered tokens
    doc = ' '.join(filtered_tokens)
    return doc

normalize_corpus = np.vectorize(normalize_document)
bible = gutenberg.sents('bible-kjv.txt')
remove_terms = punctuation + '0123456789'
remove_terms
norm_bible = [[word.lower() for word in sent if word not in remove_terms] for sent in bible]
norm_bible = [' '.join(tok_sent) for tok_sent in norm_bible]
norm_bible = filter(None, normalize_corpus(norm_bible))
norm_bible = [tok_sent for tok_sent in norm_bible if len(tok_sent.split()) > 2]

from keras.preprocessing import text

tokenizer = text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(norm_bible)

word2id = tokenizer.word_index
id2word = {v:k for k, v in word2id.items()}

vocab_size = len(word2id) + 1
embed_size = 100
wids = [[word2id[w] for w in text.text_to_word_sequence(doc)] for doc in norm_bible]

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams

skip_grams = [skipgrams(wid, vocabulary_size=vocab_size, window_size=10) for wid in wids]

from keras.layers import Add
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Reshape
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.merge import Dot
from keras.models import Model

word_input = Input(shape=(1,), name="word_input")
word = Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size,embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",input_length=1)(word_input)
word = Reshape(target_shape=(embed_size,))(word)

context_input = Input(shape=(1,), name="context_input")
context = Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size,embeddings_initializer="glorot_uniform",input_length=1)(context_input)
context = Reshape(target_shape=(embed_size,))(context)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dot(axes=1)([word, context]))
```

After the last line I'm getting the error like -

```
The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("dot_6/MatMul:0", shape=(?, 100, 100), dtype=float32)
```

wondering why its happening?

Comment: You are mixing the Functional and Sequential API, and that is not necessary at all. Just use the Functional API for everything.